# If in yii error show outputing before error

Tags: yii

When in Yii 1.1.14 I get some critical error or even not critical warning I get standart error message and all page output is hidden.
I would like in debugging mode :

1) to see all page output when was outputing before error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just enable yii debuging mode in main `index.php`. Set true if there is false.

```
 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
```