# Yii not showing any error

Tags: php, yii, error-handling

Can't make Yii to show error to webbrowser. Configured custom error handler in *config*:

```
'errorHandler' => array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ),
```

But all errors only got written to *application.log* and then Apache servers empty page with *error 500*. How to make Yii print errors to the screen?

*index.php*:

```
// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
```

Comment: Have you set YII_DEBUG to true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If in yii error show outputing before error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843038/if-in-yii-error-show-outputing-before-error)

Answer (score 5):

You should a little bit modify your `config/main.php`. There is an item `errorHandler`. It should look like this:

```php
'errorHandler' => [
    // use 'site/error' action to display errors
    'errorAction' => YII_DEBUG ? null : 'site/error',
],
```

This happened due to increased priority of `CErrorHandler::$errorAction`. Here is discussion: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/3760

Answer (score 4):

It might be more of an Apache setting. What you have is correct.

Mine also has this one.

defined('YII_DEBUG_SHOW_PROFILER') or define('YII_DEBUG_SHOW_PROFILER',true);

You can also do this.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_startup_errors","1");
ini_set("display_errors","1");
```

Answer (score 0):

read runtime/logs/app.log 
you can see any action and error that happens in you yii2 app.